# Статический класс qt

Tags: qt, c++

Создаю класс, в нем есть 2 метода и статические свойства для хранения данных.
Задача: имеется 2 класса, один из них изменяет значения статического класса, а второй считывает.

Подключаю его:

```
#include <userdata.h>
```

Статические класс:

```
class UserData {

public:

    static QString TOKEN;
    static QString UID;

    static void setToken ( QString token );
    static void setUID ( QString uid );

    struct MusicData {
        QString title;
        QString url;
        int id;
    };

    static int COUNT;

    struct Music {

        MusicData *n = new MusicData[COUNT];

    };

    static Music musicList; };
```

При обращении к его свойству `UserData::musicList.n[i].id = i;` пишет ошибку:

> error: undefined reference to `UserData::musicList'

Так же при описании методов

```
static void UserData::setToken ( QString token ) {
  TOKEN = token;
}

static void UserData::setUID(QString uid) {
    UID = uid;
}
```

тоже пишет ошибку:

> error: cannot declare member function
> 'static void
> UserData::setToken(QString)' to have
> static linkage [-fpermissive]
>      static void UserData::setToken ( QString token ) {

P.S. Не бейте. )
                                                ^

Comment: В каком файле вы пытаетесь определить методы?

Answer (score 4):

Сделайте класс синглтоном, решите сразу все проблемы=)

нашел проблему)
в UserData.cpp добавьте

```
UserData::Music UserData::musicList;
int UserData::COUNT;
```

Статические члены класса надо описывать  еще и в .cpp файле.